# Flash Media Interactive Server with MogileFS

Tags: flv, webdav, flash-media-server, mogilefs

Is it possible to get Flash Media Interactive Server working in conjunction with MogileFS? What it boils down to is that I need FMIS to fetch the FLV files from MogileFS over HTTP. As far as I can tell, however, the FMIS can only fetch and stream files from a local store :/

Anyone have experience with this or other ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a psuedo streaming setup using the PHP xmoov script, then fetch the needed bytes of the files from MogileFS using PHP, and then push them to the client one chuck at the time.